# Changing the source code does not live update using docker-compose and volumes on mern stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I would like to implement a hot reloading functionality from development evinronement such that when i change anything in the source code it will reflect the changes up to the docker container by mounting the volume and hence see the changes live in my localhost.

Below is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  server:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      # don't overwrite this folder in container with the local one
      - ./app/node_modules
      # map current local directory to the /app inside the container
      #This is a must for development in order to update our container whenever a change to the source code is made. Without this, you would have to rebuild the image each time you make a change to source code.
      - ./server:/app
    # ports:
    #   - 3001:3001
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV}
      MONGO_URI: mongodb://${MONGO_ROOT_USERNAME}:${MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD}@mongodb
    networks:
      - anfel-network

  client:
    stdin_open: true
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./app/node_modules
      - ./client:/app
    # ports:
    #   - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - server
    networks:
      - anfel-network

  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_ROOT_USERNAME}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      # for persistence storage
      - mongodb-data:/data/db
    networks:
      - anfel-network

  # mongo express used during development
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: ${MONGO_ROOT_USERNAME}
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: ${MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT: 27017
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: mongodb
      ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - mongodb-data
    networks:
      - anfel-network

  nginx:
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - server
      - client
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    networks:
      - anfel-network
    # volumes:
    #   - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

networks:
  anfel-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  mongodb-data:
    driver: local
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you just use `node` directly on the host?  You can set its database configuration to point at databases in containers, but do the core development in a normal non-Docker environment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/), [this](https://mherman.org/blog/dockerizing-a-react-app/) can help you